# How to NULL the repeating column data?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Is there a way to NULL the values that are known to be the same in the rest of the dataset?

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> `p1`.`id`,
    -> `p1`.`name`,
    -> `pp1`.`name` `product_property_name`,
    -> `pp1`.`value` `product_property_name`
    -> FROM
    -> `product` `p1`
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> `product_property` `pp1`
    -> ON
    -> `p1`.`id` = `pp1`.`product_id`;
+----+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id | name | product_property_name | product_property_name |
+----+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Tar  | foo                   | bar                   |
|  1 | Tar  | foo1                  | bar1                  |
|  1 | Tar  | foo2                  | bar2                  |
|  2 | Qaz  | too                   | doo                   |
|  2 | Qaz  | too1                  | doo1                  |
+----+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this case `product` is returned more than once because of `INNER JOIN` with `product_property`. I only need the first row of every product to group the results.

Therefore, the desired output:

```
+----+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id | name | product_property_name | product_property_name |
+----+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Tar  | foo                   | bar                   |
|  1 | NULL | foo1                  | bar1                  |
|  1 | NULL | foo2                  | bar2                  |
|  2 | Qaz  | too                   | doo                   |
|  2 | NULL | too1                  | doo1                  |
+----+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

This would allow to dramatically cut the memory utilisation, esp. when grouping large datasets.

Comment: "This would allow to dramatically cut the memory utilisation, esp. when grouping large datasets." --- uhm, what? What is the **real** issue you're solving at the moment?

Comment: The end result (expressed in JSON) is https://gist.github.com/gajus/d4189e04d438d336594f.

Comment: it doesn't explain **why** you need to make them `null`

Comment: The real query includes far more repeating columns. In the context of hundreds of thousands of rows, thats a lot of redundant data.

Comment: so? Why do you need that?

Comment: Being able to `null` the columns, I could easily cut memory use from 700M (present) to at least half.

Comment: PHP storing MySQL output in an array.

Comment: Why do you need to store all the data at once? Process it row by row. With the expected output format - it's not a problem.

Comment: That's a partial solution to my problem. Though, it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Every question is preceded by a task it solves. For the issue you've explained there is a trivial solution - process it row by row. If you have another issue - explain it as well. There is a chance there is a better solution that doesn't imply having the dataset in such a weird form. PS: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: And, uhm, assuming you *really* need the whole dataset in php memory. Why don't you create if by iterating the result set row by row and `null`ing "redundant" columns?

Comment: While analysing your suggestions I have realised that my issue is further down the road. Having a dataset with nulled value wouldn't have solved my issue in the first place. Though you are right, I can simple prepare the array with nulled value by iterating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using variables:

```
SELECT `p1`.`id`,
       (case when name <> @prevname then `p1`.`name` end) as name,
       `pp1`.`name` as `product_property_name`,
       `pp1`.`value` as `product_property_name`,
       @prevname := name
FROM `product` `p1` INNER JOIN
     `product_property` `pp1` cross join
     (select @prevname := '') const
     ON `p1`.`id` = `pp1`.`product_id`;
```

Although this works in practice, it is not guaranteed to work, because MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of the evaluation of columns in a `select` statement (so in theory the `@prevname := name` could happen first).

However, you might consider using `group_concat()` instead, and dispensing with the multiple rows per property:

```
SELECT `p1`.`id`,
       `p1`.`name`,
       group_concat(pp1.name, ', ') as product_property_names,
       group_concat(pp1.value, ', ') as product_property_values
FROM `product` `p1` INNER JOIN
     `product_property` `pp1`
     ON `p1`.`id` = `pp1`.`product_id`
group by p1.id, p1.name;
```

Or, as a single pair:

```
SELECT `p1`.`id`,
       `p1`.`name`,
       group_concat(concat(pp1.name, '=', pp1.value), '; ') as product_property_pairs
FROM `product` `p1` INNER JOIN
     `product_property` `pp1`
     ON `p1`.`id` = `pp1`.`product_id`
group by p1.id, p1.name;
```

The latter two should reduce the space more than the first solution.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` happened to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Gajus Kuizinas: and that has nothing to do with the original question :-) Another XY-problem you see?